# why no client certificate received in my IIS hosted web service?

Tags: web-services, iis, ssl-certificate

I have an asmx web service, which I am trying to verify client certificate:

```
var cert = Context.Request.ClientCertificate.Certificate;
if (cert == null || cert.Length == 0)
{
    throw new ArgumentException("certificate can not be found");
}
```

My testing code is like this in a console app:

```
ServiceReference1.PortfolioImportSoapClient import = new ServiceReference1.PortfolioImportSoapClient();
X509Certificate2 x509 = new X509Certificate2(@"D:\zurichpdf\publickey.cer");
import.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = x509;
var model = new ServiceReference1.PortfolioMessageModel();
model.ClientID = 1;
import.ImportTransactionPortfolio(model);
```

What I can see is that from the console app, the client certificate is included. But at the server side, Context.Request.ClientCertificate.Certificate is empty.

I checked the config file, it has something like this:

```
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="PortfolioImportSoap" >
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
```

Can someone tell me why the x509 certificate is not passed to my asmx web service? Should I set some security mode here as well?

Many Thanks

Comment: Is there a chance that BaisHttpBinding doesn't support passing certficate?

Comment: I think asmx file may not support certificate verification now as BasicHttpBinding is quite limited in that area. I changed it to wcf service and then it works after some configuration setting